# VB.NET Custom Control (custom drawing) Refresh issue

Tags: vb.net, controls, gdi+

I've created a simple solution with 2 projects. The 1st project (class library) contains a custom control called Container which draws itself with rounded corners. The 2nd project (windows forms) is a test application.

If I add a Container instance to main Form in the 2nd project it shows the rounded corners nicely. Also when I run the 2nd project I can see the Container.

However when I start moving the form (click and hold the title bar), especially when I move it very fast, all the drawing is messed up, drawn over and over again but not clearing it's surface first...

I can call Container1.Refresh() in the Form1.Move event, but I don't want to set this every time because this also means I have to call Container1.Refresh() in the `Form1.Resize` event and who knows which other event...

Is there an event in the Container (control) class itself where I should call Me.Refresh() or Me.Update() or Me.Invalidate() ?

For reference (Form1.vb)

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Move(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Move
    Me.Container1.Refresh()
End Sub
End Class
```

for reference (Container.vb):

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Public Class Container : Inherits Control
    Private _Gp As GraphicsPath

    Private Sub Container_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint

        Dim r As Rectangle = e.ClipRectangle
        Dim gp As New GraphicsPath
        Dim cs As Integer = 25 'CornerSize'

        r.Inflate(-5, -5)

        gp.AddArc(r.X, r.Y, cs, cs, 180, 90)
        gp.AddArc(r.X + r.Width - cs, r.Y, cs, cs, 270, 90)
        gp.AddArc(r.X + r.Width - cs, r.Y + r.Height - cs, cs, cs, 0, 90)
        gp.AddArc(r.X, r.Y + r.Height - cs, cs, cs, 90, 90)

        Dim t As Single = cs / 2 + r.Y
        gp.AddLine(r.X, r.Y + r.Height - cs, r.X, t)

        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, gp)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
Dim r As Rectangle = e.ClipRectangle
```

Change it to:

```
Dim r As Rectangle = Me.ClientRectangle
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me as though your `Container` class isn't painting its entire area - normally a control is responsible for painting its *entire* rectangle.

In order to have a control that doesn't do this - that has transparent areas (like your rounded corners) - you need to give your control the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` property. Note that this is a Windows API subject, not a .NET one, so you're heading in the direction of some minor voodoo.

While it's written in C#, the CodeProject article [Making Transparent Controls with C# and .NET 3.5](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/transparent_controls.aspx) does seem directly relevant to what you're trying to achieve.

To quote that article, you first need to override the constructor of your UserControl and configure the background:

```
public TranspControl()
{
     SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
     SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
     this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
}
```

Then, you need to override the `CreateParams()` method to set the control style `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x20;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be necessary to force a redraw here (under normal circumstances) since that redraw is automatically forced as soon as your control gets nudged.

However, what you *need* to do is clearing the background of your control before painting anything else: otherwise, your painting operation will mingle with previous painting processes. Just add an

```
e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor)
```

before your other drawing operations in the `Paint` event handler. Also, consider using the `OnPaint` method rather than the `Paint` event since you subclass the control and don't *need* to resort to the `Paint` event handler.

For the record, `Refresh` forces a synchronous redraw which is usually not desired. Rather, use `Invalidate` which enqueues the redraw request into the default window message queue.

Comment: calling Graphics.Clear still doesn't really do the trick...

This is what happens: http://img300.imageshack.us/my.php?image=drawmessjp0.jpg

Comment: ropstah: in your picture the background isn't cleared. Have you *recompiled* the project after adding the clearing code? It should look different then. However, recompiling is necessary for the IDE to take notice of the changes!